# My links are not valid 404 - but they work

Tags: html, validation, email, hyperlink

I'm making a HTML email, and both mail-tester.com and APSIS (used for the mailsending) says my links are not valid. Mail-tester.com even says it's due to 404 error.

But the links seems to work perfectly, and there are no redirects on the landing pages.
I've tried without "http://www." without "http://" and with "https://www." nothing works.

One of the links are: http://www.pieces.com/ch/de/pc/taschen/

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: you need to show the code that generates the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran a quick test and it shows that your http://www.pieces.com/ch/de/pc/taschen/ is redirecting and it goes in the redirection loop.

I used the PHP code below to run the test and it displays 302 status.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.pieces.com/ch/de/pc/taschen/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

### Output from above code

```
string(1482) "HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 12:08:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=deab085ac358b1274491824dc5d66f1fa1474546098; expires=Fri, 22-Sep-17 12:08:18 GMT; path=/; domain=.pieces.com; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: dwac_bc082iaaiTywMaaadqlmYUVd5G=lUjZtUYWQgLlxQ-B8pRhFjq09pk656tca_c%3D|dw-only|||EUR|false|Etc%2FUTC|true; Path=/
Set-Cookie: cqcid=abW4tbokf50J6NfqTag61V8Hut; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sid=lUjZtUYWQgLlxQ-B8pRhFjq09p"...
```

Also See the screenshot below which shows three *302* status before actually getting to the url.

[image: Redirection Loop]
So, it looks the url is indeed invalid. It goes into redirection loop. You should talk to your server guy to resolve this issue. Let us know if this helped you to resolve your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't know what it means but I'll pass on your information.

Comment: Sure. if this helped you, please do not forget to mark my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I just ran a test on http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and it shows the loop you mention. But I never thought it was a redirect issue, thanks a lot!